# How to show a big image for the share preview if there is a quoted text?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

Currently, when I'm trying to share a post with quoted text I see a small image in preview mode, but the real shared post has a big image. Is there a way to show big images in preview mode as well?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use height & width

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
```

Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.

If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in the link page post, but the size will be much smaller